# Is it possible to use Waze's deep link to navigate with multiple stops?

Tags: android, waze

Pretty much what it says in the title, i want to make an app that makes the driver go to multiple stops before arriving to his destination, is there a way to accomplish this with [waze's deeplinks?](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks)

I don't think it'll make much difference but the app i am developing is for an android device.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet, im not actively looking for it at this moment though.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I know its possible

Comment: I did not, im surprised that the google guide for it does not mention this once.